# Find the probability that he does not pass either examination?

Tags: probability

A student sits for two exams, theory and practical. He estimates that the probability of passing the theory examination (Te) is 0.5, the probability of passing the practical examination (Pa) is 0.3 and the probability of passing both examinations is 0.2.

1. Find the probability that he does not pass either examination?
2. Find the probability that he passes exactly one examination?
3. Given that he does not pass the theory examination, find the probability that he passes the practical exam?

**Answers**

P(Te) = 0.5

P(Te)' = 0.5

P(Pa) = 0.3

P(Pa)'  = 0.7

P ( Te ∩ Pa ) = 0.2  ; Given

1. P(not pass either examination) = P (Te'∩ Pa') = P(Te ∪ Pa)'

   ```
                              = 1 - P(Te ∪ Pa)
                              = 1 - { P(Te) + P(Pa) - P(Te ∩ Pa) }
                              = 1 - { 0.5 + 0.3 - 0.2}
                              = 0.4
   ```
2. P(passes exactly one examination) = P (Pa ∩ Te') + P (Te ∩ Pa')

   ```
                               = P (Pa) - P (Pa ∩ Te)  + P (Te) - P (Pa ∩ Te)
                               = 0.3 - 0.2 + 0.5 - 0.2
                               = 0.4
   ```
3. P( Pa | Te' ) = {P ( Pa ∩ Te' )} / P ( Te' )

   ```
            = {P(Pa) - P (Pa ∩ Te)}  /   P (Te')
            = (0.3 - 0.2) / 0.5
            = 0.2
   ```

Are those answers correct??

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You might want to use the tag [solution-verification] tag.

Comment: Yes. Your answers are correct.